# Find a good formulae

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

We know that equation $$s_1+s_2+s_3=n-1 \quad \mbox{$s_1,s_2,s_3$}\geq 1$$
 has $\binom{n-2}{2}$ solution.
I want to find any good formulae for the following form :

$$\sum\limits_{(s_1,s_2,s_3)}\prod_{i=1}^3\binom{s_i+s_{i-1}-1}{s_i}=?$$
where, $s_0=1$ and each $(s_1,s_2,s_3)$ is the solution of above equaiton.

> - My all attempts have failed.

$\textbf{Edit}:$ I also note that following:
$$n=4\Longrightarrow 1$$
$$n=5\Longrightarrow 5$$
$$n=6\Longrightarrow 18$$
$$n=7\Longrightarrow 53$$
$$n=8\Longrightarrow 169$$
$$n=9\Longrightarrow 502$$

Comment: $\sum\limits_{(s_1,s_2,s_3)}\prod_{i=1}^3\binom{s_i+s_{i-1}-1}{s_i}=\sum\limits_{(s_1,s_2,s_3)}\prod_{i=2}^3\binom{s_i+s_{i-1}-1}{s_i}$

since $\forall s_1,\binom {s_1+s_0-1}{s_1}=\binom{s_1}{s_1}=1$.

The product just has two terms.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri, thank you I know it . But, it is not help to me for answer.